# how to pagination in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: php, pagination, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I would like to create a pagination in PrestaShop 1.7

I have a function with an array, which I assign to a `.tpl` template

```
$brands = $this->getBrands();
$this->context->smarty->assign($brands);
parent::initContent();
$this->setTemplate('brandschr.tpl');
```

I have not found much information how to use `pagination.tpl` or an example how to do it.

Please send me your idea if you have done it before or any example for me.

Comment: pagination for products or what?

Comment: It can be products, brands or categories, the idea is to make a pagination in prestashop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to assign smarty variably only to the pages where it is needed. So let's say you want to add brands to your custom pagination, you only assign this on the pages that actually contain a brand.

```
$brands = $this->getBrands();
$this->context->smarty->assign($customPagination);
```

And then create an override in the theme at `/templates/_partials/pagination.tpl`.
In this file, just check if your "customPagination" isset and then display your `custom-pagination.tpl` (`brandschr.tpl`)

This will keep the original PS pagination intact.